# Debugger stepping in if statement and lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, visual-studio-debugging

Using the following code as an example:

```
if (true)
{
    string foo = null;
    List<string> bar = new List<string>
    {
        "test"
    };
    bar.Any(t => t == foo);
}
```

If I run this program in a regular way (without a break point or any other interruption), everything works without exception or error (as you would expect it).

Now if I put a break point on the if statement and move the cursor to the curly brace as described in the following picture (using my mouse, not using F10, so skipping the `if(true)` statement):

[image]

I get an exception of type `System.NullReferenceException` when the debugger executes the statement `string foo = null`

It seems to be linked to the fact that the variable `foo` is used in the lambda expression inside the `if` statement. I have tested and reproduced this on Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 (pro and ultimate).

Any idea on why this could be happening?

Comment: You should check generate IL, but most likely your variable is captured into class created to get a closure necessary for lambda expression, and that class instance is not there yet (or you skipped it's initialization when you skipped `if(true)` check.

Comment: Can't verify, but this looks like the underlying object to which `foo` is hoisted into (since it is captured by the lambda) isn't being allocated when you skip the `if` statement.

Comment: When you say it seems to be linked to the fact that the variable foo is used in the lambda does that mean if you take out the later use of foo it stops failing? It all seems very odd though since it shouldn't really throw an exception on a simple assignment...

Comment: @Chris The "simple" assignment is not so simple: it's secretly assigning to a field of a hidden object of compiler-only accessible type. It's actually very complicated!

Comment: Another observation (which confirms the "hidden object isn't allocated" theory): if you move the declaration of `foo` outside the `if` statement, the error goes away, likely because we now need to allocate the object prior to the `if` statement. It appears that all block-level allocations for those objects are tied to the line with the if statement, at least as far as the debugger knows. The lesson as always: there's nothing "simple" about closures in C#.

Comment: [Closures are no joke](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).  Maybe because it's null the compiler is moving the operation, unknownly after the lamba expression.

Comment: It requires the lambda expression and the `if` (or probably any?) statement to throw the exception. While I can understand that the generated code is way more complex than this simple c# sample, the null reference exception thrown doesn't really feel right...

Comment: @cheesemacfly What else would you expect the exception to be when you dereference null?

Comment: @dlev that makes way more sense now. I just couldn't see the problem at first since I was skipping a (finally not so) unrelated statement and "simply" assigning `null` to a brand new variable. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eric's answer and comments already describe why it can happens in general.
I'd like to highlight whats going on in this particular case.

Here is a generated IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> bar,
        [1] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> <>g__initLocal0,
        [2] class StackOverflow.Program/<>c__DisplayClass2 CS$<>8__locals3,
        [3] bool CS$4$0000)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0002: stloc.3 
    L_0003: newobj instance void StackOverflow.Program/<>c__DisplayClass2::.ctor()
    L_0008: stloc.2 
    L_0009: nop 
    L_000a: ldloc.2 
    L_000b: ldnull 
    L_000c: stfld string StackOverflow.Program/<>c__DisplayClass2::foo
    L_0011: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::.ctor()
    L_0016: stloc.1 
    L_0017: ldloc.1 
    L_0018: ldstr "test"
    L_001d: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::Add(!0)
    L_0022: nop 
    L_0023: ldloc.1 
    L_0024: stloc.0 
    L_0025: ldloc.0 
    L_0026: ldloc.2 
    L_0027: ldftn instance bool StackOverflow.Program/<>c__DisplayClass2::<Main>b__1(string)
    L_002d: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Func`2<string, bool>::.ctor(object, native int)
    L_0032: call bool [System.Core]System.Linq.Enumerable::Any<string>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!0, bool>)
    L_0037: pop 
    L_0038: nop 
    L_0039: ret 
}
```

Note `L_0003` line. It calls ctor for auto-generated `c__DisplayClass2` class, which hold `foo` field, since you use it in a lambda. So `NullReferenceException` happens because your skip class initialization, but then you assigning instance's field `foo` on a line `L_000c`.

Too bad, there is no easy way to debug on IL level to verify this, but we can debug JITed program (Debug -> Disassembly)

Here is your first breakpoint:

[image]

And then after cursor move:

[image]

One of these skiped call instructures must be call to ctor from `L_0003`.

Answer (score 9):

The comments which conjecture that you are skipping the generation of the closure are correct. C# programs are not guaranteed to have any particular behavior when you move the instruction pointer. If it hurts when you do that, don't do it.

actually that is a small lie. There are guarantees. For example, you are guaranteed that doing so in a verifiable program will not corrupt the internal data structures of the clr. You are guaranteed that doing so will not misalign the stack. and so on. But no guarantees are expressed or implied wrt your data structures! You move the instruction pointer at your peril.

Comment: I guess I should take the `[...]drag the arrow. This may have unintended consequences` warning more seriously :) Thanks for your answer